# Android & IOS - Send notification between devices

Tags: android, ios, node.js, push-notification, notifications

I've got a new requirement from the client that he would like to receive and send notifications between two applications and platform.

For example let's say we are similar to the Uber application and I've got two different apps, one for the customer and the other one for the driver.

If the customer sends a request to the nearest driver, the driver will receive a new notification that describes the pickup time and more info. The same thing will happen to the customer.

When the driver picks up the request or declines it, the customer will receive a notification showing the status of the request.

Another thing that I would like to add, is a broadcast notification for all users. Since we have an admin for the system, the admin would like to send a broadcast message for all users, something like an announcement for new updates, offers and so on.

What is the best approach for doing that, even if I should implement another server using Java, NodeJs.

But I need a good solution, plus good tutorials if available.

Thanks

Comment: https://firebase.google.com/ check it out.

Answer (score 1):

This all thing should be manage from server side. You can not send notification directly from your ios or android device to another one. First your request (from your ios or android device) goes to your server and your server will generate the notification according to your request and sent it to relative devices whether it is ios or android!

Comment: Oh sounds cool, ok do you have an idea of how to develop that. My back-end server is built using java but should i implement another third server using NodeJs to do that?

Comment: It is very broad thing to explain here that how to develop that! I don't have much knowledge from server side but i don't think you require another server for the same!